# software load balancer

Tags: load-balancing

I have two dedicated servers each running identical app, they don't need to share states/database, what's a recommended http load balancer?

Edit:
thanks for the answers below. Apache http server already supports this:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
   BalancerMember http://192.168.1.50:80
   BalancerMember http://192.168.1.51:80
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /test balancer://mycluster/
```

Is that all I need to do?

Comment: what OS/technology are you targeting?

Comment: Windows 2003, Apache http server, MYSQL 5.0, application server is Tomcat

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). I would recommend it for nearly anything. It even comes with a nice statistics layer so that you can easily see when a server goes down. From the website:

> HAProxy is a free, very fast and
>   reliable solution offering high
>   availability, load balancing, and
>   proxying for TCP and HTTP-based
>   applications. It is particularly
>   suited for web sites crawling under
>   very high loads while needing
>   persistence or Layer7 processing.
>   Supporting tens of thousands of
>   connections is clearly realistic with
>   todays hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Web server will do it, too. That's actually used in production for a site at my job with about 10,000 in-house users.

Comment: That said, I'm afraid I can't tell you much more about this. Configuring Apache is somebody else's job :)

Answer (score 0):

[Balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html), I've used it for small loads, seems to work fine. haven't pushed it very hard though.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) quite successfully in the past, as another alternative.